# SqlAlchemy - apply filter before join statement

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I try to add some contribution on [3c7](https://github.com/3c7/yaramanager)'s cool project, and I want to apply a filter on a join query(sqlalchemy).

Simple statement: multiple rules(table) can have multiple tags(table) - I want to filter out some rules based on some tags.

```
[Rules][2] table   (rule_id, etc)
[Tags][2] Table    (tag_id, etc)
tags_rules(Junction table) (rule_id,tag_id) -- no declaration
```

Issue: Applying a filter after join of course that will remove only the rules that have only one tag(the one that I specify). If a rule has multiple tags, one record from the join result will be removed, but the rule will still appear in there are any other tags associated with that rule

Sql alchemy declaration:

```
class Rule(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(255), index=True)
    meta = relationship("Meta", back_populates="rule", cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan")
    strings = relationship("String", back_populates="rule", cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan")
    condition = Column(Text)
    imports = Column(Integer)
    tags = relationship("Tag", back_populates="rules", secondary=tags_rules)
    ruleset_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("ruleset.id"))
    ruleset = relationship("Ruleset", back_populates="rules")

class Tag(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String(255), index=True)
    rules = relationship("Rule", back_populates="tags", secondary=tags_rules)
```

I tried with sub queries but the most feasible seem to apply a filter on the tags table before the join.

Current implementation:

```
rules = rules.select_from(Tag).join(Rule.tags).filter(~Tag.name.in_(tags))
```

Any idea is greatly appreciated.